# How to use cmd to get full value of a registry key with with space?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-10, registry

I want to use cmd to get PATH (enviroment variable) in registry with cmd. and here is the root of the value:`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Environment` and the value of `Path` in the dictionary is the one i want to get value. i've tried this `reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v "Path"`,but the output of it is this:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Environment
    Path    REG_EXPAND_SZ    D:\VMware Workstation Pro\bin\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot\bin;%INTEL_DEV_REDIST%redist\intel64\compiler;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;D:\ffmpeg\bin;D:\mingw64\bin;
```

I want to get  `D:\VMware Workstation Pro\bin\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot\bin;%INTEL_DEV_REDIST%redist\intel64\compiler;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;D:\ffmpeg\bin;D:\mingw64\bin` in the output. i've tried a lot on the internet.But many of the answers are not support space(because there are some space in the value) or with bugs.

I want to know ho to fix the problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do not use `ControlSet001` `ControlSet002` `ControlSet003` etc. To be sure you are getting the content from the currently running Windows session, use `CurrentControlSet` instead. To output only the content you require you need to isolate it from the command results. You can do that by using a `FOR /F` loop, and selecting the appropriate options:

From [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)

```bash
For /F "EOL=H Tokens=2,*" %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlset\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /V Path 2^>NUL') Do @Echo %H
```

From a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file)

```bash
@For /F "EOL=H Tokens=2,*" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query
 "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlset\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /V Path
 2^>NUL') Do @Echo %%H
```

As you can see the content is assigned to `%H` in [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) or `%%H` in a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), and output in this case, using the `ECHO` command